# ¿como puedo insertar una columna de una tabla en una bd a otra tabla de otra bd?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una bd llamada **primeros** y dentro de ella una tabla llamada **visitas** con una columna llamada **identificador**.
Mi otra bd se llama **segundos** y dentro de ella una tabla llamada **visitas** con una columna llamada **identificador**.
¿como puedo pasar la columna **identificador**  de la tabla **visitas** de la bd **primeros** a  **segundos** donde el **identificador** es **maestros**?

Esto es lo que me gustaría:

```
  INSERT INTO visitas(identificador)<segundos>
  SELECT identificador FROM visitas <primeros>
  WHERE identificador='maestros';
```

¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución... y queda así:

```
 INSERT INTO segundos.visitas(identificador)
 SELECT identificador FROM primeros.visitas
 WHERE identificador = 'maestros';
```